# "npm run build" in Dockerfile: dist folder is generated but disappears

Tags: docker, npm, webpack, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `Dockerfile` for a Django and Vue.js app that I use along with `Gitlab`.

The problem that I'm about to describe only happens when deploying via `Gitlab CI` and the corresponding `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. When running the `docker-compose up` command in my local machine, this doesn happen.

So I run `docker-compose up` and all the instructions in the Dockerfile run apparently fine. But when I check the production server, the `dist` folder (where the `bundle.js` and `bundle.css` should be stored) doesn't exist.

The logs that are spit out while running the `Dockerfile` confirm that the `npm install` and `npm run build` commands are run, and it even confirms that the `dist/bundle.js` and `dist/bundle.css` files have been generated. But for some reason they seem to be deleted.

This is my ***Dockerfile***:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER My Name

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY ./app .

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
      gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY app/frontend/package*.json ./frontend/

# Install npm
RUN  apk add --update nodejs && apk add --update nodejs-npm

# install project dependencies
WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN npm install

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

RUN adduser -D user
USER user

CMD ["sh ../scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the ***.gitlab-ci.yml*** file:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - echo "Runnig before_script"
  - sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
  - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
  - pip install docker-compose

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Testing the app"
    - docker-compose run app sh -c "python /app/manage.py test && flake8"

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
    - production
    - feature/gitlab_ci
  script:
    - echo "Building the app"
    - docker-compose build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
    - develop
    - feature/gitlab_ci
  script:
    - echo "Deploying the app"
    - docker-compose up --build -d
```

This is the content of the ***docker-compose.yml*** file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

This is the content of the ***entrypoint.sh*** file:

```
#!/bin/bash

(cd .. && ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput)
# Migration files are commited to git. Makemigrations is not needed.
# ./manage.py makemigrations app_name
(cd .. && ./manage.py migrate)
```

I would like to know why the `dist/` folder disappears and how to keep it.

Comment: Could you add the content of the `entrypoint.sh` file?

Comment: can you also post the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Mihai I just edited my original post with the content of `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk I just edited my original post with the content of entrypoint.sh

Comment: In your docker-compose you don't need the "volumes:  - ./app:/app". First of all you don't have it on the server. That would explain why it works in local. Can you try without it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When your `docker-compose.yml` file says

```
volumes:
  - ./app:/app
```

that hides everything that your Dockerfile builds in the `/app` directory and replaces it with whatever's in your local system.  If your host doesn't have a `./app/frontend/dist` then your container won't have that path either, regardless of whatever the Dockerfile does.

I would generally recommend just deleting this `volumes:` block entirely.  It introduces an awkward live-development path (where all of your tooling needs to know that the actual service runs in Docker) and simultaneously isn't what you'd run in development (you want the image to be self-contained and not to need to copy the application separately from the image).

Answer (score 1):

In your compose file, you set a volume which is going to replace your local environment with the one in your container even after `npm run build`

```
 volumes:
  - ./app:/app
```

You can either build it in your local or remove `volumes`

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with a nestjs build. Lately we noticed, that we had excluded the src file in the `.dockerignore`.

Answer (score -3):

Issue is not with docker file. It issue with your dependency. please check package.json file in root folder.